# Elasticity Value for Log-Log and Level-Level Model

Tags: regression, econometrics, elasticity

For a data if I calculate Elasticity using
1) **log-log model** with Elasticity = Beta and 
2) Calculate elasticity in **Level-Level** Model with elasticity = beta *(X/Y)

**should the resultant value of elasticity be same.. ?** In my case the value is not same. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this expected? I am not from an econometrics background. any links would be helpful

Comment: These terms need context for interpretation, could you provide more context?

Comment: I am trying to calculate elasticity of a product. Now If I calculate it using the log-log model or level-level model should the resultant elasticity value be the same. Because mine is not.